# How to display custom keyboard when clicking on edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom keyboard in  my application. question is How to didplay this keyboard when click on the edittext.I an using setonfocuschangre listener ,now the custon keyboaed appears when the edittext focus is changed.but i want to show this keyboard whenever i click on the edittext..one info I forget to put here the edittext is within the fragment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I created a Custom Keyboard in my application using Keyboard tag. I am adding this keyboard in a RelativeLayout on my screen like.

```
private void createCustomKeyboard() {
  Keyboard customKeyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.layout.keyboard);
  CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(getActivity(), this);
  mCustomKeyboard.setKeyboard(customKeyboard);
  RelativeLayout relLayKeyboard.addView(mCustomKeyboard);  
}
```

If you want to use this CustomKeyboard on one or more than one EditText then you have to use below code :

```
EditText edtxtName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
RelativeLayout relLayKeyboard = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relLay_keyboard);
edtxtName.setOnTouchListener(exitSoftKeyBoard);

private final OnTouchListener exitSoftKeyBoard = new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    if(v.equals(edtxtName)){
        edtxtName.requestFocus();
        relLayKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
    return true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this

```
    edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom keyboard again,
                   // by tapping on an edit box that already had focus (but that had the keyboard hidden).
                    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                        showCustomKeyboard(v);
                    }
          });


          // Disable standard keyboard hard way
          // NOTE There is also an easy way: 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' 
         // (but you will not have a cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
                edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                        int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
                        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
                        edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
                        edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
                        return true; // Consume touch event
                    }
                });


        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

For more info check [here](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)

Comment: I will try this for sure one info I forget to put here the edittext is within the fragment..

Answer (score 3):

You can actually create an **InputConnection** for your **CustomKeyBoard** and then set this connection to your **EditText**

**Using InputConnection, your CustomKeyBoard will replace the android keyboard and work as default.**

You can get code from Here:
https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps/

**keyboard.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Delete"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Enter"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

**MyKeyBoard.java :**

```
public class MyKeyboard extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button1, button2, button3, button4,
                button5, button6, button7, button8,
                button9, button0, buttonDelete, buttonEnter;

private SparseArray<String> keyValues = new SparseArray<>();
private InputConnection inputConnection;

public MyKeyboard(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.keyboard, this, true);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(this);
    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
    button0.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
    buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);

    keyValues.put(R.id.button_1, "1");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_2, "2");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_3, "3");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_4, "4");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_5, "5");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_6, "6");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_7, "7");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_8, "8");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_9, "9");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_0, "0");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_enter, "\n");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (inputConnection == null)
        return;

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_delete) {
        CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
            inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        } else {
            inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
        }
    } else {
        String value = keyValues.get(view.getId());
        inputConnection.commitText(value, 1);
    }
}

public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
    inputConnection = ic;
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ssaurel.inappkeyboard.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c9c9f1"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <com.ssaurel.inappkeyboard.MyKeyboard
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        MyKeyboard keyboard = (MyKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
        keyboard.setInputConnection(ic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);` to disable the default keyboard and then set a click listener to show your own keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Use `onClickListener` like following:

```
edit_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        custom_keyboard.open();
    }
});
```

Or you can do this:

```
edit_text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                custom_keyboard.open();
            else
                custom_keyboard.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the onclicklistener to show my popupleyboard  and also the hides the keyboard within the listener. thankx for your help....

Answer (score 1):

Initiate the **InputConnection** of your edit text and create methods to delete and enter texts when your custom keyboard view is performed with any user actions.

Declare `inputConnection` on the activity `onCreate` method as below;

```
InputConnection inputConnection = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
```

When you **enter** any text execute the below code.

```
inputConnection.commitText(text, 1);
```

When you click the **clear / backspace** button execute the below code.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputConnection.getSelectedText(0))) {
    inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
} else {
    inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
}
```