# How can I make the soft keyboard invalid when an EditText is focused

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

When I click an `EditText`, the soft keyboard appears. I don't want the keyboard to appear when I clicked an `EditText`, however, I want to get `EditText`'s forces. I want to edit it without the keyboard.

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
});
```

In this code, the keyboard doesn't appear when I click once. But the keyboard appears when I click many times successively.

How can I improve it?
Please tell me how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: please explain what actually you want because you can make editText unclickable but then there no meaning of Edittext so instead of using edittext you can use textview. please explain about your output

Comment: @user7359831 try my answer :)

Comment: I want to use my keyboard. I am making calculator, so I don't need the keyboard.

Comment: i think you need this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31721154/2356808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Key :**

`onCheckIsTextEditor()` Check whether the called view is a text editor, in which case it would make sense to automatically display a soft input window for it. This Returns true if this view is a text editor. So let's change that! Then keyboard does not appear :)

**Create  your own  class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
    public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**set your xml like this**

```
  <your.package.name.NoImeEditText
         android:textSize="17dp"
         android:textColor="#FFF"
         android:id="@+id/edit_query"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

**call it**

```
 editText = (NoImeEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_query);
```

**check focus**

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                      // show your custom key pad and do your work 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The keyboard appears when I click many time at the same time.

Comment: @user7359831 Now try

Comment: Thanks. There are some conditions. input some letters and click them on. it doesn't work. On the other hand, it works when theres no letters in editText.

Comment: @user7359831 tell exactly what you want? do you want to display the curser? you only need to make edit text clickable ?  or both? or else?

Comment: @Charuka , all he wants  "i want to use my keyboard" :D

Comment: editText = (NoImeEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_query); this part. NoImeEditText should be EditText. There an error when I run it.

Comment: have you created that class? and you have to make your xml Edit text with that name `<your.package.name.NoImeEditText` and when you initialize it it should be `NoImeEditText editText  = ...`

Comment: I think you are correct, but I can't do it. Please tell me more specific. I appreciate it.

Comment: There is a class called `NoImeEditText ` ok. You can rename it as you want but if its messy keep it as it is. Now you need to creare `EditText`s from that class.Then keyboard does not appear. So when you add your  `EditText` it should be that type.Thats why u need to use `<yourpakgeName.NoImeEditText ...` in xml.Then also when you initialize it use that type.not normal `EditText` then when you run keyboarddoes not appear!so set a listener to that edit text and you can display your own keyboard there when it hasFocus

Comment: I made it finally! Thank you a lot!

Comment: `onCheckIsTextEditor()`

Check whether the called view is a text editor, in which case it would make sense to automatically display a soft input window for it. 

So your soft keyboard gets called when you click it every time.That's why we wrote that custom class returning result as false.So no more softkeyborad

Comment: @user7359831 you can accept the answer if its helpful :))