# Enabling customized keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to develop an app on android where the user is able to enter their input through the keyboard that I design. However, I am running with an issue with the phone built in keyboard. My question is, is there a way I can disable the built in the phone keyboard and just let my own keyboard running when the user wants to enter their input? I searched around but could not find something helpful. Your guidance will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it was useful. I was able to get it to work @billa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Satya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2234616/satya?tab=profile) already answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786272/how-to-display-custom-keyboard-when-clicking-on-edittext-in-android) .

Its just the same what you need. In that he showed a custom keyboard on clicking input text box. You can change it as you want.

Comment: @ThisIsMi I am happy to hear it helped, upvote it too thus it would help someone in future.